# RS485 from UART of Orange Pi 5 plus

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, integrated-circuit, uart, rs485

I'm trying to make a PCB "hat" for an Orange Pi 5 plus.

What I want to accomplish:

- 3x RS485 using UART of the Orange Pi and 3pcs [ADM1485ARMZ](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adm1485.html)
- 2x CANbus (already built in). Can I just draw traces for this, or does it need termination?

My questions are about the RS485 IC. I have seen a lot of examples of biasing resistors in different values, so I feel unsure about what I should use, if any. Also, I have seen different ways of connecting RO, RE, DO, and DI.

I will use 5 V as VCC; this is because I want the RS485 to have a 5 V signal.

Could anyone please help me sort this out, or explain how I should do this?

The picture shows how far I have come at the moment.

[image]

Using the THVD1426:

[image: Texas Instruments THVD1426]

[image: New thoughts when using the THVD1426]

Comment: So to answer what you should do, we would know what you intend to do with this, how do you connect it and where? If you connect to existing bus that's terminated and biased, you really do not want termination and biasing enabled on your board. You might not need the biasing, unless you intend to communicate with a bus that requires them and your board as master should provide them. Different bus standards use different biasing and terminations, so which bus you will be connecting to, and how many devices there are already? Also Orange Pi has 3.3V IO so it will fry if you connect to 5V IO.

Comment: sorry i totally missed this reply, im new to the platform so maybe that is why.

i will try to answer your questions as good as i can.

-  "we would know what you intend to do with this"
i am makeing a pcb that connects on an GPIO header of an Orange pi 5 plus, from this pcb i need to get 3pcs rs485 (1 channel for inverter, 1channel for heatpump and 1channel for Meters)
 and 2pcs CAN (1channel för inverter and 1channel that is free), also i am using one SPI channel for isoSPI (battery monitoring, this already works)

Comment: - "how do you connect it and where"
im planning to connect this on the Orange Pi 5 Plus GPIO header
the rs485 i would like to use UART tx,rx and if needed as less gpio's as needed

the CAN is built in for Orange pi 5 plus, i have thought that i need termination resistor on the pcb 120ohm, but im not cleart if i need some more components on the CAN circuit.

- "If you connect to existing bus that's terminated and biased, you really do not want termination and biasing enabled on your board. You might not need the biasing"

Comment: i can just tell that the UART does not have any biasing what i know of.

- "Different bus standards use different biasing and terminations, so which bus you will be connecting to"

i will connect to Modbus

- "and how many devices there are already?"
the inverter is by itself, the heatpump is also by itself for now, there may be some more device connected in the future.
the re are 2 meters connected to the last rs485

- "Also Orange Pi has 3.3V IO so it will fry if you connect to 5V IO"
VERY good point, i need something to reduce the signal to the Orange pi

Comment: thanks alot for getting me to think :) @Justme

Answer (score 0):

If you want a multidrop bus, you only want termination resistors on the first and last device. The devices in the middle of the wire must not have termination resistors. You can make termination optional (with a jumper) or don't include termination at all (so that the user must manually connect a termination resistor to the first and last device).

Regarding the RO, RE, DE and DI pins:

- RO (receiver output) must be connected to the UART RX pin of the microcontroller.
- /RE (not receiver enable) must be connected to a GPIO pin of the microcontroller (and your software must switch the GPIO as required) or tied to GND if you want the receiver always on (which means you will receive your own transmission while sending).
- DI (driver input) must be connected to the UART TX pin of the microcontroller
- DE (driver enable) must be connected to a GPIO pin of the microcontroller and your software must switch the GPIO so that only one device on the bus speaks at any given time. You can tie /RE and DE together and control them with a single GPIO pin (low for receive, high for transmit).

If you don't want to switch between transmit and receive using GPIO pins, you can use a RS485 driver with auto direction sensing, such as the Texas Instruments THVD1406.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply :)

the ic you reccomended seems like a better choice for me, also Texas instruments had very good documentation and examples. this can make it possible to use the way i want without usiong any GPIOs.

- yes i want multidrop as you say so i will keep the termination on the pcb and make sure the last device have termination to.

Comment: i got some follow up questions for the THVD1426 (refering to the Ti Layout example added picture above)
- what resistor value should i chose on "RO" to VCC (if i should put a resistor here?)
- Capacitor on Vcc to gnd value 100nF - 220nF, is this something i need to calculate?
- the pullup resistor how do i chose the correct value?

maybe all the above is unnessesary? 

alot of thoughts

Comment: I think blindly switching to auto direction sensing IC before checking how the auto sensing works is a bad idea. It will take time before the transmitter gets enabled from data, and it takes time before transmitter disables after data, and during long sequence of data high such as low baud rate or many high bits in a row can disable the transmitter even when you wanted to be active. So think hard if you really want to subject your design to to auto sensing chip and let it handle the direction for you so you lose control of it yourself. 5V supply will still fry Pi and RS485 may expect 5V.

Comment: I see your point @Justme and i agree with you, this will not be good enought for the inverter where many messages are sent the whole time. Also the transmitter can not be disabled, that will be very bad for the function of the inverter. And also I need to put some component on the UART and GPIO to reduce the voltage down to 3.3v as you say, just don’t know what to chose